# How to configure phone number in LG l7 (P-708)

Tags: settings

i can't setup the phone number in:

- Settings -> About phone -> Status -> My phone number

[image: Menu1] [image: Change phone number]

How i can change it in the LG L7 P-708?

It has installed Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to set is the [MSISDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN) number on your SIM card. This can be quite difficult to do on Android. [This](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/giffgaff-Top-Tips/How-to-add-your-mobile-number-to-your-phone/td-p/483867) site has a post detailing how it can be done on various phones (including non-Android) which if you have access to another device is probably the easiest way.

If you don't have access to another device then you could try the [myphonenumber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.lytsing.myphonenumber) app. This is very flaky and only works on certain ROMS/devices.

The other option is to contact your operator as I believe this is something that they can set OTA, although most don't seem to know anything about it from my experience.

Comment: Greath, the solution works for Galaxy S (GTI9000)  - tested on 2.1 and 2.2 - Goto Contacts > Settings > Own Numbers > Create a new entry called My Number > reboot phone - C&P from link